# Can't use useEffect in React 18

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, react-dom, react-18

Recently I updated my react version from 17 to 18 and one of the pages in my NextJs projects started to throw an error:
`TypeError: destroy is not a function`

I've already googled this error before and I couln't find anything useful.

I found where is the error but I don't know what can I do to fix it.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setupChart() // Async function
}, [])

async function setupChart() {
    try {
      const config = {,
        options: {...},
      }
      Chart.register(...registerables);
      const newChart = new Chart(
        canvas.current,
        config
      )
      newChart.update()
      setChart(newChart)
    } catch (e) {
      return 0
    }
  }
```

The message shows when setupChart is in the function. I've seen some people returning a async function or even returning a anonymous function but both way didn't work for me.

I also tried to use `await setupChart()` or `setupChart().then(...)`, but didn't work.

**SOLVED!!!**

I read the error message and it says i should return undefined or nothing instead of null ( i.imgur.com/LTbWvIj.png) Above that code block I had another useEffect which was the responsable for the error (https://i.imgur.com/m1kQycE.png)

Comment: Can you show the whole error? Dos it mention where it's coming from? Normally it gives you an idea.

Comment: @YoussoufOumar sure! 
https://i.imgur.com/c0dXjiE.png
https://i.imgur.com/LTbWvIj.png

Comment: @YoussoufOumar so i found out what was going on. Basically as the error message says, I should return undefined when my functions doesn't have a cleaning function. I did that and it worked